# tcl: how to execute tcl command with custom list argument

Tags: tcl

I have this example tcl code that works by itself:

```
layout peek -celltext "CellA" "CellB"
```

I would like to have the a list storing CellA and CellB such that I want to execute something like

```
set list [list "CellA" "CellB"]
set OUTPUT [layout peek -celltext [exec echo $list]]
```

Unfortuantely, spending 2 hours and various combination isn't getting me anywhere. Any ideas on what I need to do? Forgive me as i'm not strong in Tcl programming.

Comment: `layout peek -celltext {*}$list` see https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M9

Comment: Shawn, that worked!!

Comment: FYI: `[exec echo $list]` doesn't return a value.  Writing to stdout is different than returning a value.

Comment: `[exec echo $list]` does return a value, because `exec` captures stdout from the things it runs. But it's almost just the same as straight `$list` (the differences relate to binary data) while being much more expensive.